# categorizing products based on the salePercentage in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This task seems simple but I am stuck here.
 I have a problem statement to segregate products into 3 categories (F,M,S) based on their salePercentage. Following is the snapshot of dataframe.

```
                        grandTotal  saleRatio   
product             
587a                      33330841.0    11.147972 
58cb                        20050510.0  6.706177    
587e                        15157320.0  5.069581    
58cf                        11811805.0  3.950626    
58bg                       10723140.0   3.586506
```

I need to assign a 'F' status to those group of products which generate 60% of revenue. Next 30% would be 'M' and last 10% should be 'S'.

What's the best way to do so. I have tried following :

```
s=0
index_60=[]
index_30=[]
index_10=[]
for i in productSaleValue.index.values:
    if(s<=60):
        index_60.append(i)
        s=s+productSaleValue.saleRatio[i]
    if ((s>60)&(s<=90)):
        s=s+productSaleValue.saleRatio[i]
        index_30.append(i)
    elif ((s>90)&(s<=100)):
        s=s+productSaleValue.saleRatio[i]
        index_10.append(i)
```

But I am loosing on data on this. Kindly share

Comment: How are you calculating salePercentage?

Comment: Are `salePercentage`, `saleRatio` and "percent of revenue" the same thing?

Comment: yes @gayo . 'saleRatio' is basically revenue percentage earned by that product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.cumsum()` to get the cumulative sum of a column.

See an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
in_data = np.random.random(10)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = in_data
df['fraction'] = df['A'] / df['A'].sum()
df.sort_values(by='fraction', inplace=True)
df['csum'] = df.fraction.cumsum()
df_60 = df[df.csum <= 0.60]
df_30 = df[(df.csum > 0.60) & (df.csum <= 0.90)]
df_10 = df[df.csum > 0.90]
```